# Why I initialise a struct in this way make my phone crashed?

Tags: c++, struct

I defined a struct:

```
typedef struct myStruct{
   int32 iMem1;
   int16 sMem2;
   int32 iMem3;
}myStruct;
```

And initialise it:

```
void main(){
   myStruct s1 = {0, 1, 0};
   return 0;
}
```

When I run it in my phone, it crashed my phone.

If I initialise it another way:

```
void main(){
    myStruct s1 = {0};
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is ok!

I doubt about it!

Comment: This doesn't look like the reason for a runtime crash, the issue is probably somehwhere else. Is this the full program that causes a crash?

Answer (score 0):

Both struct initializations are fine, assuming `int32` and `int16` are types.  However, `main` must return an int:

```
int main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's nothing to do with main, because I use int main(), it also crash my phone.

I think it's the struct's alignment(int16, int32) cause the crash, but I doubt about it.